# How to solve Leverage browser caching issue in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5, browser-cache, cache-control

I am using php laravel framework.
I have tried to solve **Leverage browser caching**. But its still showing

[image]

in my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 5 minutes"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 5 minutes"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access 5 minutes"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access 5 minutes"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access 2 minutes"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access 2 minutes"
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 2 minutes"
  ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 2 minutes"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 2 minutes"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 5 minutes"
  ExpiresDefault "access 2 minutes"
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|swf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=60, public"
  </filesmatch>
  <filesmatch "\.(html|htm)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=60, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesmatch>
  <filesmatch "\.(pdf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=60, public"
  </filesmatch>
  <filesmatch "\.(js)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=90, private"
  </filesmatch>
</IfModule>
```

in my apache **mod_rewrite** & **mod_headers** are enabled

[image]

### Updated

I have set caching time to 1 week. less than one week is not working properly.

How can i solve it?

Comment: Use a longer caching time (minimum 2 hours is for static ressources recommended)

Comment: I have set caching time to 1 week. less than one week is not working properly.

Comment: From Google "We recommend a minimum cache time of one week and preferably up to one year for static assets, or assets that change infrequently"

Comment: Suppose i have made some changes in my js files with in one week. Which 'js' file browser access "cached" or "updated"?

Comment: Since it's cached, the cached file. Adding `must-revalidate` to the header might help.

Comment: ok. thank you very much